Nodejs pdf manipulation with pdf-lib package
I am trying to implement a auto download feature in a project I'm working on. I am using the pdf-lib npm package to get data from input fields from a front-end and automatically populate a pdf form. I achieve this by using body-parser to get the data from the front-end, save them to variables and input these variables in an editable pdf form using the pdf-lib package. Currently the only way to access the file is to go into the root folder and open the pdf file in file explorer. I want to automate that as well such that once the data is submitted and the input fields are propagated, the document automatically downloads onto my computer in say the "downloads" folder. Any help will be appreciated. Find code below.
index.js file:
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const { PDFDocument } = require('pdf-lib')
const { readFile, writeFile } = require('fs/promises')
require('dotenv').config()


const app = express();


// Setting view engine to use ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

// Serving static files
app.use(express.static('public'))

// Use body-parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

const port = process.env.PORT


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index")
})

app.post("/submit", (req, res)=>{
let name = req.body.full_name;
let location = req.body.location;
let requirements = req.body.requirements

console.log(name)
console.log(location)
console.log(requirements)
async function createPdf(input, output) {
    try {
        const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(await readFile(input))
        let fieldNames = pdfDoc.getForm().getFields()
        fieldNames = fieldNames.map((f) => f.getName())

        const form = pdfDoc.getForm()
        form.getTextField(fieldNames[0]).setText(name)
        form.getTextField(fieldNames[1]).setText(location)
        form.getTextField(fieldNames[2]).setText(requirements)

        const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save()

        await writeFile(output, pdfBytes)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

createPdf("public/assets/pdf/test_document.pdf", "result.pdf")
res.render("index")
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server started successfully")
})

index.ejs file:
<%- include ("includes/header", { "title" : "Home" }) %>


<div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <form action="/submit" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group mt-3">
                  <label for="">Full Name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="full_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your full name" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mt-3">
                  <label for="">Location</label>
                  <input type="text" name="location" class="form-control" placeholder="Location" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mt-3">
                  <label for="floatingTextarea">Requirements</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Describe your requirements to us" id="floatingTextarea" name="requirements"></textarea>
                  
                </div>

              <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">
          </form>
          
      </div>
  </div>
</div>



  <%- include ("includes/footer") %>

